# Creating an SQL table with email address as title

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm struggling to create SQL tables using email addresses as the table name.

The code I am using produces the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
>   name VARCHAR' at line 1

and the related code is:

```
// create new table for users tosses
    // Make a MySQL Connection
        mysql_connect("localhost", "$sqlusername", "$sqlpassword") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());

// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $emailaddress(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        name VARCHAR(30), 
        age INT)")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

It works just fine when I input a value from the variable `$emailaddress` that is not an email address i.e. doesnt have an `@` symbol, but it shows that error if it includes an `@` symbol.

Comment: What have you determined to be valid characters for use in table names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to get around this by escaping the table name with backticks (`). But really for most circumstances this is a bad way to design your database.

You should use one table with an emailaddress field instead of creating a new table for each user/email address, unless you have a specific need to do so.

Comment: RyanP thanks. Can you help me think out if this is REALLY a bad way to do things for my site:    There is one main table for users that logs email address and passwords.  Each username is the same as their email address.  Then each user gets a table created in their name to track their file uploads and about 15 other relevent variables that relate to the user.  I think this was a good set up because, each users account will have a good deal of activity (new rows filling in 15 variables or so).    Is there a better set up? I am new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not using backticks. Using backticks allows you to choose identifiers more freely:

```
CREATE TABLE `$emailaddress` ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name VARCHAR(30), age INT)
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

`Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:`

`ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F`

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be to your advantage to have one table designed as follows

```
CREATE TABLE emailaddr
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    name VARCHAR(30),
    age INT,
    unique key (email)
);
```

The reason I suggest this is in the event you have to add more fields to the table, you only have to alter one table. With the design you are using, you would have to query a table that may not exist yet (something mysql would do for you upfront). Should you add fields, you have to cycle through hundreds, probably thousands, of table to make needed changes.

You could query for an email address like this:

```
SELECT * FROM db_name.emailaddr where email = '$emailaddress';
```

With your design, you must check if the table exists first

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name = '$emailaddress';
```

Then, if the table count is 1, then you could

```
SELECT * FROM db_name.`$emailaddress`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
// create new table for users tosses
    // Make a MySQL Connection
        mysql_connect("localhost", "$sqlusername", "$sqlpassword") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());

// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$emailaddress`(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        name VARCHAR(30), 
        age INT)")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

You need back ticks "`" around the variable.