# Special Characters in table name in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-tablelayout

I am creating an android application where tables are created dynamically having email (for example:abcd@efg.com) as their table name. Later I learned that table names cannot have special characters like "@".
Please suggest me a way by which I can create tables with special characters like "@" and "." in the table name.

Comment: Is this [tag:sqlite] or [tag:mysql]? It's currently tagged with both.

Comment: I am not certain why you think that having a table per email address is the appropriate solution. Even if it is, use a supported table name (sequentially or randomly generated), and have a table that maps email addresses to table names.

Comment: @Mureinik: Its SQLite. Do you have a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.  The brief answer is that SQLite supports both double quotes and square braces for escaping identifiers.

However, the correct answer is that I cannot imagine why a separate table would be created for each email.  An email address is typically an attribute of an entity, and hence a column.  Even if an email address represented an entity itself, then you would want to store multiple emails *in a single table* with the email as a primary key.

If, for some reason, you need temporary tables for some processing for individual users, then use `create temporary table`.

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558952/creating-an-sql-table-with-email-address-as-title)

Based on above link, U can do it using

> `

around the email address.
but as it is said it is really bad practice.